# Bootstrap table toggle ...how to close previous toggle if a new one is opened?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

First of all, a jsFiddle of my code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/ae1Lxcc1/3/

I have a Bootstrap table where people can open and close a toggle with additional information. They each have different IDs like `toggle-00001`, `toggle-00002`, but may also be `toggle-43894`.

I use this for each ID:

```
$(".toggle-00001").on('click', function (event){
 event.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass("row-selected");
    $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').toggleClass("row-selected");
    $(".details-00001").slideToggle("fast");
    $(this).html(function(i,html) {
    if (html.indexOf('color-grey') != -1 ){
        html = html.replace('icon-grey','icon-green');
    } else {
        html = html.replace('icon-green','icon-grey');
    }
    return html;
 });
});
```

Is there any simple way, without rewriting most of the code, to make it so that if a new one is toggled, the other one is closed?

In other words, I'd like there to be only 1 toggle open at all times, so that a user can't open 100 at once.

Thank you for any advice you can give :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really need to optimize your code. First of all, you don't want to duplicated click handler for every row, what if you have 100 of them?

What you can do is just give the same class to `details` and `toggle` rows and after that JS will become simpler:

```
$(".toggle").on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();


    var $row = $(this).closest('tr'),
        $nextRow = $row.next('tr.details');

    $('tr').not($nextRow).not($row).removeClass('row-selected');

    $nextRow.add($row).toggleClass("row-selected");

    $(this).html(function (i, html) {
        if (html.indexOf('color-grey') != -1) {
            html = html.replace('icon-grey', 'icon-green');
        } else {
            html = html.replace('icon-green', 'icon-grey');
        }
        return html;
    });
});
```

I also moved style="display: none" to CSS (`.details` class):

```
.details {
    display: none;
}
.row-selected {
    background-color: #DDD;
    display: table-row;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ae1Lxcc1/4/

Finally, toggling icons can also be optimized to just:

```
$(this).find('.color-gray').toggleClass('.icon-grey .icon-green');
```